# Add a list of changes from an Excel file to an email using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a list of departments on a worksheet named "Weekly Changes".

[image]

There are multiple departments but only FY22 and FY23 all set up the same way going down the worksheet.

I have VBA code to create an email. I want to find all the changes from weekly changes that are more than 10% in Column E and list them in the email.

Email example:

```
Hello All,

Weekly Changes:

Department 1 - FY23 - Product A 11%

Department 2 - FY22 - Product A 15% - Product C 94%                                                   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FY23 - Product B 23% - Product C 11%

Thank You,

ME
```

VBA code to create email that is located in a module on the workbook containing the weekly changes work sheet:

```vb
Sub Email()
    
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutLookMailItem
        .Display
    End With
    
    EBody = "Hello All," _
      & "<br><br>" _
      & "Weekly Changes" & "<br>" _
      & "List of Changes?" _
      & "Thank You," & "<br>" _
      & "ME"
    
    With OutLookMailItem
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "Weekly Changes"
        .HTMLbody = EBody
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The best way to get consistent results with minimal coding would be to start with the data in a more database like style where every line item includes the department and FY. Line1) `Dept2 | FY22 | ProdA | 103 | 99 | 4 | 0.0404` Line2) `Dept2 | FY22 | ProdB | 471 | 83 | 388 | 4.67`               It can be done all programmatically, this is going to let the user debug the easiest. Then, just cycles cells (or pull into array and cycle) and add each cell > 10% to `EBody`

Comment: @CameronCritchlow I changed my output to match the database style that you showed here, but I still can't figure out how to get the "each cell > 10%" actually put into the EBody I always get a type mismatch error

Comment: not sure where your type mismatch error is, but the code I posted below doesn't give me any type mismatch errors. Show me the line the mismatch happens on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, we have our data already being nicely converted to line entries with some array formulas:

[image]

Store in array and check each value:
Add to email.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Build_Email(ebody As String, eSubject As String, eRecipient As String)
    
    Dim OLApp As Object
    Dim OLMailItem As Object
    
    Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OLMailItem = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OLMailItem
        .To = eRecipient
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = eSubject
        .HTMLBody = ebody
        .Display        'Only Use Display or Send and comment out the other
        '.Send          'Only Use Display or Send and comment out the other
    End With
    
End Sub
Sub Identify_Line_Entries_Over_10Percent()
    
    Dim I As Integer    'Iteration
    Dim LineEntries     'Array of all line entries
    Dim ChangeList As String    'List of all changes > 10%
    
    ' > Store Line entries
    LineEntries = Sheet1.Range("O3:T" & Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' > Cycle each line entry to check
    For I = 1 To UBound(LineEntries, 1)
        Debug.Print LineEntries(I, 6)
        ' > Check if change is > 10%
        If LineEntries(I, 6) > 10 Then
            ChangeList = ChangeList & _
                " -) " & LineEntries(I, 1) & " - " & LineEntries(I, 2) & " - " & _
                LineEntries(I, 3) & " - " & LineEntries(I, 4) & " - " & _
                LineEntries(I, 5) & " - " & Format(LineEntries(I, 6), "0.00") & "% <br>"
        End If
    Next I
    
    ' >>> Passing all Variables to Email Sub
    Build_Email _
    "Hello All, <br><br>" & _
    "Please note the below changes for your review: <br><br>" & _
    ChangeList & "<br>" & _
    "Thank You, <br><br>" & _
    "ME", _
    "Weekly Changes", _
    "Someone@hotmail.com"

End Sub
```

And final output looks like this:

[image]